# Apache2: AH00035: access denied

Tags: php, apache2

I'm getting a lot of errors in my logs like the following one get this error when trying to access localhost via a browser.

```
[Tue May 09 15:10:21.527729 2023] [core:error] [pid 26955] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:34088] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/hazemhagrass/workspace') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Tue May 09 15:10:21.539244 2023] [core:error] [pid 26957] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:34096] AH00035: access to /robots.txt denied (filesystem path '/home/hazemhagrass/workspace') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Tue May 09 15:10:21.620151 2023] [core:error] [pid 26955] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:34088] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/hazemhagrass/workspace') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://localhost/
```

Here is a screenshot from my browser

A screenshot from my browser:
[image]

Here is my configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

# Indexes + Directory Root.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
DocumentRoot /home/hazemhagrass/workspace/wordpress/demo

<Directory "/home/hazemhagrass/workspace/wordpress/demo">
      AllowOverride All
      Options FollowSymLinks
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
Require all granted

    </Directory>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php)?$ [OR]
    RewriteCond $1 \.(gif|jpg|png|ico|css|js)$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [S=1]
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END wordpress
    
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/demo-access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/demo-error.log
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the double slash with a single slash in both `/home/hazemhagrass//workspace/wordpress/demo`?

Comment: Thanks for catching it but it's not working though